# Spring boot- How to kill session on browser close or on all tab close but not on single tab close

Tags: spring-security

**What i have done till now**

1) Restricted user from multiple login. (using Spring boot security)
Provided session time out is 30 Min.(Required)

2) Kill/Invalidate session on browser close. (using beforeunload event from main.jsp)

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
Utils.ajaxCall('GET', "/logout", '', '', '', false);
```

});

**What is the Issue ?**

My spring boot application supports multiple tabs, As one page provides link that open another page in another tab.
When i close any tab out of opened tab, Session getting killed.

How to handle following scenario?

1) Kill session on browser closed event only?

2) Not to kill session on tab closed, But on last tab.

3) Not to kill session if another browser window is opened..as session is still accessible from that browser.

**What is the GOAL
Restrict the User from multiple logins, kill the session on browser close - all tab close - last tab close(i.e Browser close).**

Comment: This is a bad idea/design.  You CANNOT be sure a client session is ending and rely on that server-side.  Let the server/Spring framework do its job and don't try to control server session from the client-side.

Comment: @Adam, thanks for advice, But how to clear session from session Registry on abruptly browser close...in such scenarios, Session getting clear from browser but not from sessionRegistry, And user getting "Already logged in" message if he tries to log in within 30 min.(session-timeOut )

Comment: @Raj did you manage to find a solution for this.

Comment: Not yet @KelvinMuia